# Взаимнооднозначное соответствие между строками ListBox и элементами коллекции

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

Есть ли какой-то эффективный способ найти строку ListBox по связанным с помощью LB_SETITEMDATA с ней данным?
Я нашёл два макроса, название одного из которых выглядит так, будто это то, что мне нужно, но вот в том, что подставляется вместо этих макросов я особых отличий не вижу, тогда как второй явно не то, что я ищу. Попробовал использовать их в качестве эксперимента, и просто слать соответствующие им сообщения тоже - не работает, только по самой строке находит индекс, а по объектам сопоставленным строке возвращает -1, что есть  LB_ERR.

```
#define ListBox_FindString(hwndCtl, indexStart, lpszFind) ((int)(DWORD)SNDMSG((hwndCtl), LB_FINDSTRING, (WPARAM)(int)(indexStart), (LPARAM)(LPCTSTR)(lpszFind)))
#define ListBox_FindItemData(hwndCtl, indexStart, data) ((int)(DWORD)SNDMSG((hwndCtl), LB_FINDSTRING, (WPARAM)(int)(indexStart), (LPARAM)(data)))
```

В MSDN сказано:

> LB_FINDSTRING attempts to find an item
> that has a long value (supplied as the
> lParam parameter of the LB_ADDSTRING
> or LB_INSERTSTRING message) that
> matches the lParam parameter.

Но в то же время в статье об LB_ADDSTRING:

> lParam A pointer to the
> null-terminated string that is to be
> added. If the list box has an
> owner-drawn style but not the
> LBS_HASSTRINGS style, this parameter
> is stored as item data instead of a
> string. You can send the
> LB_GETITEMDATA and LB_SETITEMDATA
> messages to retrieve or modify the
> item data.

Значит ли это что найти строку по item data возможно только для *the list box has an owner-drawn style but not the LBS_HASSTRINGS*? Ведь иначе имела бы место двусмысленность, например если item data является буквой, с которой начинается какая-то другая строка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никогда не храните данные в контролах! Тогда и искать их с помощью контролов не придётся.

Такой тип мышления навязывается книжками типа *"Программируем на Delphi за 13 дней"*. Нужна реакция на кнопку - вот вам `Button1_OnClick`. Нужна строка - вот вам `TextEdit1.Text`. Нужна предварительная инициализация - пожалуйста, 100 строк метода Form1_OnCreate.

Здесь и начинается спагетти-код. В обработчике нажатия кнопки мы программируем сортировку элементов `ListBox`, запуск таймера, связь с драйвером, и т. п... Появилось меню - в обработчиках меню или повторяем на 90% тот же код. Или догадываемся вызывать методы `_OnClick` кнопок.

А теперь вспомните три заветных буквы **MVC**. Ну или **MVP**, или **MVVM**, кому что больше нравится. Ведь дело не в ..C, ..P или ..VM. Дело в **Model** и **View**. **Их нужно разделять!**

**Модель** - те данные, с которыми работает программа. *Смоделируйте* предметную область, те термины которыми оперирует программа, в виде `namespace`, `package` или в виде класса. Если все данные программы - это один бит, то можно, конечно, выделить модель в одну единственную переменную типа `boolean`. Если же модель - коллекция данных, то, скорей всего, понадобятся методы добавления, удаления, поиска, сортировки данных. Тут можно придумать, что одни операции происходят чаще других, принять решение, какую *классическую структуру данных* лучше использовать. А главное - называйте объекты, классы, методы модели теми именами, которыми они называются в реальном мире. Моделируете телеком - *канал, узел, коммутатор, рабочая станция*. Моделируете институт - *студент, ведомость, оценка*. Код модели прост, понятен, красив.

**Представление** (оно же view, вьюшка) - часть программы, которая нужна для взаимодействия с пользователем. В *оконном приложении* это всяческие окна, диалоги, кнопки, поля ввода, комбобоксы... Или другой пример: *консольное приложение* - тогда представление - это два объекта *cin* и *cout*. А над ними уже масса операций - считать число, считать строку, вывести строку, вывести отформатированную строку. Третий пример:  приложение - *сервер*. В этом случае вьюшка не нужна. За сетевое взаимодействие, наверное, логичней назначить ответственным *контроллер*. Ну, идеология MV? подразумевает взаимодействие с конечным пользователем.

Так вот, если не *смешивать* код **модели** и **представления**, можно *заменить* представление. Было приложение консольным, стало оконным или стало сервером! Модель же не вросла в код отображения окошек, живет независимо. Еще один важный плюс: развитие приложения получает линейную сложность от количества фич. Вы добавляете фичу в модель и добавляете её в представление. В случае спагетти-кода вы добавляете фичу в эту адову смесь - перестаёт работать другая фича - оказывается, что во всех методах приходится разбираться с дополнительным условием - меняется код всех методов. То есть без разделения модели и представления сложность добавления фич - экспоненциальная (факториал).

Про контроллер, презентер и view-model не рассказываю, чтобы не запутать, это здесь не важно. И лучше про них узнаеть из хороших статей.

Хорошие статьи по  [MVC](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/patterns/generic-mvc.xml), [MVP](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/patterns/modelviewpresenter.xml).

***Теперь ответ на Ваш вопрос***:

Храните список в отдельной переменной (в коде модели) `CArray<CString> elements`. Насколько я понял из вопроса, со строками хранятся какие-то дополнительные данные. Тогда ваш список будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
struct CMyData {
    CString textToShow;
    int valueToSave;
};
CArray<CMyData> myDataCollection;
```

Поиск сделайте с помощью специального метода. Весьма вероятно, что у класса  `CArray<T>` уже есть метод для поиска эллементов. При каждом изменении Вашей переменной списка, обновите содержимое `ListBox` (в коде контроллера).

`LB_SETITEMDATA` Вам не нужно использовать вообще! Этот инструмент нужен для специальных целей разработчиков фреймворков, оборачивающих WinApi в классы, и других подобных задач.

Comment: Вообще-то у меня была задача написать приложение максимально быстрым и использующим минимум памяти, ведь там и речь идёт про чистые WinAPI. Стал бы я использовать WinAPI, если могу себе позволить использовать MFC и дублирование данных в модели плюс дополнительные операции синхронизации представления и модели? Бывают ситуации, когда масштабируемость, расширяемость и т. д. оказываются несущественными, и важно получить приложение, которое просто эффективно выполнит конкретную задачу здесь и сейчас. Но обычно то, что Вы предлагаете - лучшее решение, поэтому я принял ответ.